# How to find out a^b of very large numbers in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to find out `a^b` in python, of really large no.s

My code is this:

```
t=raw_input()
c=[]
for j in range(0,int(t)):
    n=raw_input()
    a=[]
    a,b= (int(i) for i in n.split(' '))
    c.extend(pow(a,b))
for j in c:
    print j
```

And I am getting an error like this:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/lastdig.py", line 7, in <module>
    c.extend(pow(a,b))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Whats wrong in my prob and is it an efficent way to find out powers of large numbers?

Comment: huh? you don't have extend on your 7th line, you have append, that wouldn't cause such error.

Comment: Plese provide the inputs you are giving to the program. Also, are you sure the source code you provided and the error match?

Comment: your question and your error are two  completely different beasts.

Comment: This code works on my machine (Python 3, changing raw_input for input)

Comment: On another note, why not just use a**b instead of pow(a,b)?

Comment: so, why you changed it to extend now? you were clearly told that you code with append had no problems.

Answer (score 3):

You are using extend wrong. A.extend( B ), requires that B is some iterable object( ie a list, tuple ).  You really want to use append instead.

```
t=raw_input()
c=[]
for j in range(0,int(t)):
    n=raw_input()
    a,b= (int(i) for i in n.split(' '))
    c.append( pow(a,b) ) ## or you could extend c.extend( [ pow(a,b) ] ), but thats silly.
for j in c:
    print j
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try [GMPY](http://gmpy.sourceforge.net/). Try something like:

```
import gmpy
a = gmpy.mpz(10**10)
b = a**10000000
```

I don't know how much "big" your numbers are, this solution isn't that fast (but the result is big enough :P )

Answer (score 2):

10000**10000 prints in my machine in under a second.

How large is your input.

Your problem is not related to power function.

Use

```
c.append()
```

instead of

```
c.extend()
```

c.extend takes an iterable (a list/tuple/set/custom iterables) as an input.

Answer (score 1):

python integer ops are arbitrary precision
If you want arbitrary precision floating point ops import Decimal

```
from decimal import *
d=Decimal('2.0')
print d**1234
```

Answer (score 1):

`x**y` works greatly for exponents. If you want a more original solution, you can use:

```
def exp(base, exponent):
  round(exponent, 0)
  if exponent < 0:
    return 1.0 / exp(base, -1 * exponent)
  if exponent == 0:
    return 1
  if exponent > 0:
    return base * exp(base, exponent - 1)`
```

Sadly, this only works exactly for integer exponents.

Comment: Hey I tried exp(2,1000) and viola max recursion depth exceeded!

Answer (score -1):

Another way you might want to try calculating exponents is by using logarithm laws.

x^y = e^(y ln x)

I can't say for certain but this might reduce the number of operations required to calculate large exponents.

Comment: I am curious to know whether this facilitates a performance benefit; It all depends on python's implementation of pow(). I am waiting for some expert comment on this.

Comment: pow() is done by repeated squaring, so it is very efficient. For moderately sized numbers the logarithm is about the same or slightly faster, but pow() is superior in general because it calculates the exact answer instead of a floating point approximation, and because it won't overflow on large numbers.